# php: variable scope, how does this file know this variable?

Tags: php, drupal, scope

My PHP is not very good so this may be a dumb question. Anyway, I'm jumping in to do some work on a commercial site. A aesthetic change needs to be made. Found the file that generates the page. The first line of the php file is this:

```
<?php if(render($content)): ?>
```

I printed out $content to see what's in it. It's a giant array with key value pairs that I think Drupal is using to render the page. But my question is...this php file has no include or define. How/where could $content be declared and populated? And how does this php file see it?

Thanks!

Comment: An include need not be for a "hard-coded" filename, but you can include a file whose name is held in a variable; so how can you be sure that this file isn't being included in that way?

Comment: this file may not be including any file. but some other file is including this file and the variable `$content` is populated in that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume we have two files `foo.php` and `bar.php`;

Code of `foo.php`

```
<?php
$greetings = 'Hello, How are you?';

include 'bar.php'
```

Code of `bar.php` is like

```
<?php
echo $greetings;
```

Now if you execute foo.php, You will see
`Hello, How are you?`

But no `$greetings` variable is printed in `foo.php`. How it is showing then? Because when you execute `foo.php` total code executed becomes like this

```
<?php
$greetings = 'Hello, How are you?';
echo $greetings;
```

The same way you see the $content value. The logic to get to that point is way more complex that the example i gave, but philosophy is same. :-)

Answer (score -1):

In drupal first file which called is index.php file and it include other files on the basis of url parameters,cookies and sessions.